# Calculator problems need solving

Tags: javascript, calculator

I need to limit the numbers I click on screen to like 10 digits. Now I can click until there is NAN showed there. I'm beginner so please help me. I also have a problem with <kbd>+/-</kbd> button so if you know how to make it work I would be thankful. Also if you can help me with when I divide by zero there is a problem with infinity I don't know how to solve that.

Here's my code until now.

```js
function getHistory() {
  return document.getElementById("history-value").innerText;
}

function printHistory(num) {
  document.getElementById("history-value").innerText = num;
}

function getOutput() {
  return document.getElementById("output-value").innerText;
}

function printOutput(num) {
  if (num == "") {
    document.getElementById("output-value").innerText = num;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output-value").innerText = getFormattedNumber(num);
  }
}

function getFormattedNumber(num) {
  var n = Number(num);
  var value = n.toLocaleString("en");
  return value;
}

function reverseNumberFormat(num) {
  return Number(num.replace(/,/g, ''));
}

var operator = document.getElementsByClassName("operator");
for (var i = 0; i < operator.length; i++) {
  operator[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.id == "clear") {
      printHistory("");
      printOutput("");
    } else if (this.id == "backspace") {
      var output = reverseNumberFormat(getOutput()).toString();
      if (output) {
        output = output.substr(0, output.length - 1);
        printOutput(output);
      }
    } else {
      var output = getOutput();
      var history = getHistory();
      if (output == "" && history != "") {
        if (isNaN(history[history.length - 1])) {
          history = history.substr(0, history.length - 1);
        }
      }
      if (output != "" || history != "") {
        output = output == "" ? output : reverseNumberFormat(output);
        history = history + output;
        if (this.id == "=") {
          var result = eval(history);
          printOutput(result);
          printHistory("");
        } else {
          history = history + this.id;
          printHistory(history);
          printOutput("");
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

var number = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
  number[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var output = reverseNumberFormat(getOutput());
    if (output != NaN) {
      output = output + this.id;
      printOutput(output);
      dot = false;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#kalkulacka {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20px;
  position: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#vysledek {
  height: 120px;
}

#historie {
  text-align: right;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
}

#output {
  text-align: right;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#klavesnice {
  height: 400px;
}

.operator,
.number,
.negate,
.dot {
  width: 50px;
  height: 44px;
  margin: 14px;
  float: left;
  border-width: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="kalkulacka">
  <div id="vysledek">
    <div id="historie">
      <p id="history-value"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="output">
      <p id="output-value"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="klavesnice">
    <button class="operator" id="clear">C</button>
    <button class="operator" id="backspace">AC</button>
    <button class="negate" id="opposite">+/-</button>
    <button class="operator" id="/">&#247;</button>
    <button class="number" id="7">7</button>
    <button class="number" id="8">8</button>
    <button class="number" id="9">9</button>
    <button class="operator" id="*">&times;</button>
    <button class="number" id="4">4</button>
    <button class="number" id="5">5</button>
    <button class="number" id="6">6</button>
    <button class="operator" id="-">-</button>
    <button class="number" id="1">1</button>
    <button class="number" id="2">2</button>
    <button class="number" id="3">3</button>
    <button class="operator" id="+">+</button>
    <button class="dot" id=".">.</button>
    <button class="number" id="0">0</button>
    <button class="operator" id="=">=</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could split this question into 3-4 separate questions with clear description of your issues and [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of posting full code with bunch of questions

Comment: Well the issue with numbers output is done. So now i need help with +/- button to make it work in this calculator. And after that there is problem when i divide number by  zero it returns as Infinity and i would like that to be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting NaN is because your casting to number in `n = Number(num)` overflows. I suggest to use the format method that you have already written in order to control the maximum amount of digits you can display. However, this means that if you perform an action for which the result is too long, a result will still be displayed, but not the correct one.

Here is my modification to it:

```
function getFormattedNumber(num) {
  if(num.length > 10){
    num = num.substr(0, 10);
  }
  var n = Number(num);
  var value = n.toLocaleString("en");
  return value;
}
```

You might want to edit this though, since in my opinion displaying an incorrect answer is even worse than displaying NaN. I would probably edit the formatting to display a message of "Overflow", or such if the string is too long. And then clear the field automatically on next click.

Comment: Yes this was verry helpfull and its working thank you verry much. :) Now i need help with +/- and divide by zero problem. So if you would have time and be willing to help i would apreciate it. But still thank you for this :)

Comment: Happy to help. I will take a look at the other issues when I have some spare time.

Comment: Yea thank you. I resolved other issues i had with this but thank you. But noticed a new one. For example you have 2,34 but i can still add "," after it resolve in 2,34,24 and you dont want that. So need to think of something to solve this issue.